# GNU Octave/Matlab Matrices Manipulation

Tags: struct, octave

I'm quite new to GNU Octave, so can anyone help me for 2 things:
(1) How can I filter that huge dataset in such a way that it will only contain [1x1 struct] persons?
(2) Inside that value of struct, I only want to retain combined_categories. How can I delete the others?

Basically, my end goal is to have a dataset with 2 columns only (filename and combined_categories of the filtered 1x1 structs). And if I can convert that to csv, that would be more awesome.

[image: Snippet of GNU Octave]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question, how to filter a struct. First step is to create a vector which decides which ones to keep and which ones to delete:

```
%Get the data for the relevant field
persons={test.person}
%For each field, check if the size is 1
one_person=cellfun(@numel,persons)==1
%Select those you want
test=test(one_person)
```

About your second question, please check the documentation for [rmfield](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rmfield.html)

Comment: Thanks! It worked!. But for the 2nd one, I'm trying to do this:
>> val2.person = rmfield(val2.person,'body_bbox')
But this error keeps on showing
error: invalid dot name structure assignment because the structure array is empty.  Specify a subscript on the structure array to resolve.